# JavaScript, how to call a function

Tags: javascript, function, call, invoke

This probably sounds stupid, like "Is this guy even trying?" stupid. But I am, desperately, trying. Everything Iv'e searched only shows me how to write a function, not call it back.

```
var choice1 = function(){
    var choice = 5
        while(choice != "n" || "s") {
            document.write("<p>There's a door norh of which you sit, south is a small window with a slight breeze coming through</p>");
            document.write("<p> north: door  south: window</p>");
            choice = prompt("north or south");
            if(choice == "n" || "south"){
                document.write("<p>You stand up, aching in your joints you grunt. Inspecting the door you see, what seems to be, a large iron grated cell door? ''Why would I be in a cell?'' you think to yourself.</p>")
                break
            }else if(choice == "s" || "south"){
                document.write("<p>You stand up, aching in your joints you grunt. Inspectig the window</p>");
                break
            }else if(choice != "n" || "s" || "noth" || "south") {
                document.write("<p>Please pick one of the paths</p>");
        };
    };
};

function choice1()
```

This is what I have, it works because I've tested with not being in the function but I cant get it to invoke the function.

Comment: Just do `choice1()`, not `function choice()` the second time you write this.

Comment: When you write `function choice1()` what you are doing is basically declaring another function also titled choice1()

Comment: Are you _really_ that bad at searching? [MDN's Guide On JavaScript Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) : [Defining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Defining_functions) : [Calling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions)

Comment: `choice != "n" || "s"` should be `choice != "n" || choice != "s"`

Comment: I remember my first SO question....

Comment: @Caleb: Don't be discouraged by the downvotes and negatives. It might be hard to be an absolute beginner on SO. Please go through the information others have provided and read more on MDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the function, just do:

```
choice1();
```

Comment: Sorry @user104317 it's unclear what you mean? My answer is how to call a function, as OP has asked...

Comment: @AmirTaboul said the same thing with a better explination before you did

Answer (score 1):

```
choice1()
```

Typing `function` means that you want to declare a function rather than use one.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last line `function choice1()` with:

```
choice1()
```

Comment: I tried searching and the only thing I got was example of how to write function and how to do math with function. I'm sorry, I will try to be less of  a loser next time